# mCustomScrollbar with marquee

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, marquee

i need a (div) section that will auto scroll and also have a scroll bar.

so i found this scrollbar plugin: [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) 
and a marquee plugin: [jQuery Marquee](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples)

when i am tring to connect both all working goon until i scroll the div to the bottom.

if i scroll down to the bottom the marquee dont relize that he need to get down and he start jumping until he calculate the length to the bottom and start over.

any help how to fix it..?

here is an example:

```js
$('.marquee').marquee();
$(".marquee").mCustomScrollbar();
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}

.ver {
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

<div class="marquee ver"  data-duplicated="true" data-direction='up' data-duration='5000' data-pauseOnHover="true">jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the be<br/>st marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in t<br/><br/>he world. jQuery marquee is the best marque<br/><br/>e plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee <br/><br/>plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugi<br/><br/><br/>n in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world<br/><br/>. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the be<br/>st marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in t<br/><br/>he world. jQuery marquee is the best marque<br/><br/>e plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee <br/><br/>plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugi<br/><br/><br/>n in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world<br/><br/>. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the be<br/>st marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in t<br/><br/>he world. jQuery marquee is the best marque<br/><br/>e plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee <br/><br/>plugin in the world <b>end</b>jQuery<br/><br/><br/> marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugi<br/><br/><br/>n in the world <b>end</b>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world<br/><br/>. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b></div>
```

Or Codepen : http:// codepen.io /anon/pen/raQLWY

thanks in advance.
and sorry for my middle english..